# Fuerte failure in serialization.h

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, serialization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am running "ptam" in gdb on a machine 1 with roscore. Machine 2 is running a process "remote-ptam" that publish and subscribe to machine 1. Both machines are linked to roscore on machine 1. Verified that all publishing and subscribing happens properly by viewing rxgraph. However in a certain state of "remote-ptam", "ptam" on machine 1 crashes.

I am running linaro ubuntu 12.11 on odroid u2 with ros fuerte (machine 1-compiled from source) and ubuntu 12.10 x86 desktop with ros groovy (from synaptic) on machine 2.

GDB output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8948006/gdb.txt

serialization.h: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8948006/serialization.h

back trace: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8948006/gdb_bt.txt

Is there any known bug in ROS serialization?

Aswin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53888/fuerte-failure-in-serialization.h/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was in the read/write operation which I changed to memcpy (~line 200) in serialization.h as suggested by Simon Lynen.

Updated file can be downloaded in link above.

Cheers
Aswin

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0